# Bash for loop pull text from file recursively

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am having trouble writing a Bash for loop script that can extract the contents of a specific file that is common to many child directories under a parent directory.

Directory structure:

```
/Parent/child/grand_child/great_grand_child/file
```

In which there are many child, grandchild, and great grandchild folders.

I want my script to do (in psuedo-code):

For EVERY grand_child folder, in EVERY child folder:

1. Search through ONLY ONE great_grand_child folder
2. find the file named 0001.txt
3. print the text in row 10 of 0001.txt to an output file
4. In the next Column of the output file, print the full directory path to the file that the text was extracted from.

My script so far:

```
for i in /Parent/**; do
if [ -d "$i" ]; then
echo "$i"
fi
done
```

Can I have some help designing this script?
So far this gives me the path to each grand_child folder, but I don't know how to isolate just one great_grand_child folder, and then ask for text in row 10 of the 0001.txt file inside the great_grand_child folder.

Comment: Is there only one `0001.txt` file per grandchild folder, or can there be several such files in different great-grandchild folders?  If there are many, does it matter which one is used?  Do any of the folder names contain spaces or other awkward characters?  Also, is the parent folder `/Parent` or `./Parent` (aka `Parent`)?  You mention both in the question, so it isn't clear.

Comment: Good questions. 0001.txt is in each and every GREAT_grand-child folder, so any grand_child folder has many 0001.txt within it (one per great_grand_child). It doesn't matter which 0001.txt is used, though - they all have the same data on row 10, for each grand_child folder. And no folder names contain spaces or anything besides numbers, text, and the underscore character "_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# For every grandchild directory like Parent/Child/Grandchild
for grandchild in Parent/*/*
do
   # Look for a file like $grandchild/Greatgrandchild/0001.txt
   for file in "$grandchild/"*/0001.txt
   do
     # If there is no such file, just skip this Grandchild directory.
     if [ ! -f "$file" ]
     then
       echo "Skipping $grandchild, no 0001.txt files" >&2
       continue
     fi

     # Otherwise print the 10th line and the file that it came from.
     awk 'FNR == 10 { print $0, FILENAME }' "$file"

     # Don't look at any more 0001.txt files in this Grandchild directory,
     # we only care about one of them.
     break
   done
done
```

Comment: This is great - but what can I do about the fact that each "grandchild" folder has a slightly different name? Can we use variables here instead of "grandchild"?

Comment: `grandchild` is a variable here, it's the iteration variable for the outer for loop.  Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: I liked the awk line from Jonathan Leffler's answer, so I've updated my answer with that.  I prefer my explicit loops though; Jonathan's sort is very clever but a bit obscure for my tastes, and the behavior is hard to modify (e.g. for the "Skipping" message that I added).

Comment: Yes sorry I misunderstood your code - as a variable this works just fine. upvotes all around!

Answer (score 1):

Given that the names are sane (no spaces or other awkward characters), then I'd probably go with:

```
find /Parent -name '0001.txt' |
sort -t / -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -u |
xargs awk 'FNR == 10 { print $0, FILENAME }' > output.file
```

Find the files named `0001.txt` under `/Parent`.  Sort the list so that there is just one entry per `/Parent/Child/Grandchild`.  Run `awk` as often as necessary, printing line 10 of each file along with the file name.  Capture the output in `output.file`.